# sitecore_analytics_index on Sitecore 9

Tags: xdb, xconnect

While troubleshooting issues with the Experience Profile results on a 9.0.1 recently installed instance (PaaS), I've noticed the below setting on Sitecore.ExperienceProfile.config.

```
<!-- Name of Sitecore search index that is used for contact search. -->
<searchIndex name="sitecore_analytics_index" />
```

Would this be something you'd expect on 9? I thought that index had been replaced by the xConnect's search xdb index. Did I get that wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, this is no longer an index in Sitecore 9. It has been replaced by the xDB collection index.

This is probably a left-over setting that was missed.

Per the [latest documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/architecture-overview/search.html):

> In 9.0, the following indexes are no longer managed by Sitecore
>   Content Search:
>
> - sitecore_list_index - replaced by the xDB collection index
> - sitecore_analytics_index - replaced by the xDB collection index